# Binary Search to find maximal minimum value

Tags: c++11, binary-search

I am trying to find the maximal minimum value the I can places some numbers apart in an interval. Also in the interval there is a gap, based on the input.

```
while(high-low>0)
{
    mid=(high+low)/2.0;
    distance=0;

    for(int posts=1; posts<p; posts++)
    {
        //the gap in the interval 
        if( distance+mid>a && distance+mid<b)
        {
           //if the digits falls between the gap 
           //continue the search from the edge of the gap's end
            distance = b;
            posts++;
        }
        distance += mid;
        if(distance>length)break;

    }
    if(distance==length)return mid;
    else if(distance<length)low=mid;
    else high=mid;
}
```

The problem I have is that for some values, this will not work. 
The `distance` will go close to the `length` but it will not be equal.
I tried rounding the `distance` but then the value will not be the correct one.

**Example:**

You have the distance 0-9 and 10 units. There is a gap from 5-7 where no units can be placed in between, now we have to find the distance such that no 2 units are less then this distance apart.

Comment: Is the collection you search in sorted? And can't you simply use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) or [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) or one of the other [binary search functions in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm#Binary_search_operations_.28on_sorted_ranges.29)?

Comment: The problem I am having is with the gap interval located within the collection. That is why I cannot use `std::binary_search`. i.e. In in the collection from [0,9], there is a gap (5,7). How far apart can we place 10 numbers?

Comment: You'll have to describe the problem you are trying to solve in more detail, preferably with an example. What numbers are "some numbers", what is this "interval" you want to "place" them in, what does "maximal minimum" mean?